# Twitter Streaming API with OAuth?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter, oauth, streaming

I've been stuck on this for awhile. Does anyone know how to authenticate the Twitter Streaming API requests using OAuth? As of right now I'm authenticating via Basic Authentication, and I would like to completely switch over to OAuth. Also, I'm using Ruby on Rails if that helps.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Connecting to the Twitter Streaming API via OAuth is done much the same as connecting via the REST API. Assuming you've already negotiated an access token, you sign and issue the request using the same signing algorithm as for a REST request. With the Streaming API, it's best to use header-based OAuth rather than query-string based.

Here's an example of a signed OAuth-based request for the sample end point:

GET http://stream.twitter.com/1/statuses/sample.json

**Signature Base String example:**

GET&http%3A%2F%2Fstream.twitter.com%2Fstatuses%2Fsample.json&oauth_consumer_key%3Dri8JxYK2ddwSV5xIUfNNvQ%26oauth_nonce%3DUJb0f3nHhFQkpkWkJzxnFT65xX1TZeuGjww6Q2XWs4%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1306947138%26oauth_token%3D819797-torCkTs0XK7H2Y2i1ee5iofqkMC4p7aayeEXRTmlw%26oauth_version%3D1.0

**Authorization Header after signing:**

Authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key="ri8JxYK2ddwSV5xIUfNNvQ", oauth_nonce="UJb0f3nHhFQkpkWkJzxnFT65xX1TZeuGjww6Q2XWs4", oauth_signature="bN14zlBIdCZCSl9%2B8UV8dB2VWjI%3D", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_timestamp="1306947138", oauth_token="819797-torCkTs0XK7H2Y2i1ee5iofqkMC4p7aayeEXRTmlw", oauth_version="1.0"

Matt Harris has some sample code in PHP demonstrating connecting to the streaming API via OAuth: https://github.com/themattharris/tmhOAuth/blob/master/examples/streaming.php

Comment: Hi, I looked at your answer and now I understand how to construct the base string and authorization header. However, now I'm stuck on how to actually post the data correctly to twitter stream in ruby. As of right now, I'm using yajl to create a httpstream to post to twitter stream only using basic authentication.

Answer (score 1):

After you register your application on http://dev.twitter.com this is how it's done in `Perl`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use AnyEvent::Twitter::Stream;

if ($ENV{FIREHOSE_SERVER}) {
    $AnyEvent::Twitter::Stream::STREAMING_SERVER = $ENV{FIREHOSE_SERVER};
}

my $done = AE::cv;

binmode STDOUT, ":utf8";

my $streamer = AnyEvent::Twitter::Stream->new(
    consumer_key => 'KEY',
    consumer_secret => 'SECRET',
    token => 'TOKEN',
    token_secret => 'TOKEN SECRET',
    method => "filter",
    track => "KEYWORDS TO TRACK",
    on_tweet => sub {
        # CUSTOM CODE HERE
    },
    on_error => sub {
        my $error = shift;
        warn "ERROR: $error";
        $done->send;
    },
    on_eof   => sub {
        $done->send;
    },
);

$done->recv;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the OmniAuth gem which supports many external providers https://github.com/intridea/omniauth

Answer (score 0):

You should use this gem : [Tweetstream](https://github.com/intridea/tweetstream/) which sits on top of [em-twitter](https://github.com/spagalloco/em-twitter)